# Loop through most recent objects: Rails on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to loop through the most recent "Articles" - say, 10 most recently posted within last 30 days.

Should I be creating a method in my article model something like follows:

models/articles.rb

```
def recent
  self.where('created_at > ?', Time.now-30.days.ago)
end
```

And then calling it in my views?

views

```
@articles.each do |article|
   link_to article.title, Article.recent    
end
```

This of course, does not work.

If this has been answered (maybe I was using wrong search terms - new to stackoverflow), direction is appreciated!

Comment: You should also really order your query and limit the results to 10 if thats what you want:

def self.recent
  where('created_at > ?', Time.now-30.days.ago).order("created_at desc").first(10)
end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this *should* be in a method, but a class method. I personally prefer methods over scopes for this sort of thing.

```
def self.recent
  where('created_at > ?', Time.now-30.days.ago).order("created_at desc").first(10)
end
```

In your controller, you can set `@recent_articles` with

```
@recent_articles = Article.recent
```

view you will then do

```
@recent_articles.each do |article|
  link_to article.title, article_path(article) # use your proper route method here.
end
```

Recommended (dated) Reading: http://www.railway.at/2010/03/09/named-scopes-are-dead/

Comment: I'd modify your recent method to better match what they are looking for:

def self.recent
  where('created_at > ?', Time.now-30.days.ago).order("created_at desc").first(10)
end

Comment: Deefour, thanks for the answer (on John for the update). 

Where to you stick @recent_articles = Article.recent under within the controller?

Comment: You put it in the controller action associated with the view containing your loop.

Comment: Awesome. Was having issues because I had two controller actions based on states (def all & def index). Added @recent_articles = Article.recent in both and worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`Scopes` would be a good thing to check out for something like this. Check the link [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) to read more about them.

On your `Article` model, you could create a scope called `recent` like this:

```
Class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :recent, lambda { where("created_at < ?", TimeZone.now) }
end
```

Then you retrieve these articles simply by using `Article.recent`

Answer (score 0):

I guess scope will work for you there:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes

€ Late ;)